# Creating a new variable on R

Tags: r, variables

I am wanting to make a new variable based on household income

The variable I want to change at the moment is as follows:

1- under £5000 
2- £5000-£14,999
3- £15000-£19999
4- £20000 or more

I wish to make this into

Below national average - so below and including £19,999
Above national average - £20000 or more

I have tried using codes etc but it does not seem to work.

Can anyone help? Thanks!!

Comment: where is the code you tried?

Comment: > income  <- ifelse(income<=19,000, 1, 0)          The variable name is 'income'

Comment: Hello Briony. Welcome to SO. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post. I provided an answer based on what you've posted so far, but if you could provide some sample data along with the code (and any error messages) in your question, you'll be more likely to receive a relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a factor variable, then you'll need to compare on the factor values, not a numeric value. For example:

```
id <- 1:10
income <- c("under £5000","under £5000",
            "£5000-£14,999","£5000-£14,999","£5000-£14,999",
            "£15000-£19999","£15000-£19999","£20000 or more",
            "£20000 or more","£20000 or more")

incomeData <- data.frame(id,income)
incomeData$aboveAverage <- ifelse(incomeData$income == "£20000 or more","Yes","No")
incomeData
```

...and the output:

```
> incomeData
   id         income aboveAverage
1   1    under £5000           No
2   2    under £5000           No
3   3  £5000-£14,999           No
4   4  £5000-£14,999           No
5   5  £5000-£14,999           No
6   6  £15000-£19999           No
7   7  £15000-£19999           No
8   8 £20000 or more          Yes
9   9 £20000 or more          Yes
10 10 £20000 or more          Yes
>
```